# How do I define a pair of objects in a Thrift structure?

Tags: thrift

Is there any way to create a pair of objects in thrift structure?

I need to define a thrift structure which takes Set of pairs, some thing like this.

```
set < pair<value1,value2> >
```

I can use map in place of pair only if I create a new Map for same 'value1'.

Is there any way that I can do this in thrift?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such construct as a `pair<>` or even a `tuple<>` in Thrift.

You may use a struct, but it comes with the disadvantage that you will need to do it for every combination of key/value type again, since it is **not** generic:

```
struct {
  1 : i32  key
  2 : string value
}
```

Comment: Creating a `map` just to mimic a pair sounds expensive in some languages.